Calculate zpub based on seedphrase, passphrase, and account number in Bitcoin
Can I use the bitcoinlib Python library to create a function that takes a mnemonic phrase, a passphrase and an account number and returns the corresponding zpub (purpose=84)?
Something like this:
from bitcoinlib.mnemonic import Mnemonic
from bitcoinlib.keys import HDKey

def get_zpub_from_mnemonic(mnemonic_phrase, password, account_num):
    # Get the extended public key (zpub) for the account
    return zpub

mnemonic_phrase = "abandon abandon abandon abandon abandon abandon abandon abandon abandon abandon abandon about"
password = "my_password"
account_num = 0

zpub = get_zpub_from_mnemonic(mnemonic_phrase, password, account_num)
print(zpub)


Please [edit] your question to properly format your code in a [code block]. I think syntax highlighting is the easiest way.
